# Get last added subfolder in bash?

Tags: bash

I know you can get the last modified folder, but can you get the last added folder? Or actually what I want is the first added folder.

I've got a script that forks and downloads my Flatiron lessons into a folder, and since I manually get the lessons in order and then move them into a "done" folder when they're done, the oldest folder in the lessons folder should be the next lesson I'm ready for. So it would be nice to have a script to call up the next lesson, but the folder may have been modified since it was added (accidentally maybe) so sort by modified wouldn't work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible but you will need to use stat(1):

```
for a in *; do stat -c "%n %w" "$a"; done
```

will display all files with time of creation in human readable form; using `%W` (upper case) will print a unix timestamp instead, suitable for passing the output to sort(1), which is what you probably want. See `man stat` for details.

UPDATE after comment

Triplee points out that the loop is not necessary, and actually I overlooked that (never used stat before...). So the above command can be simplified to:

```
stat -c "%n %w" *
```

and the output stream can be read or piped in whatever way is desired.

UPDATE FOR USE WITH SORT

After having a list of files with associated date, they can be sorted:

```
stat -c "%W %n" *
```

... outputs something like:

> 1415945135 conf openwrt.txt
>   1424503577 triton
>   1440843167 alterwifi.txt
>   1465755258 brushless.txt

For every line, the first number is the time of creation date in "seconds form The Epoch"; the second field is the file name.

This can be sorted, and then filtered to get only the first line, which indicates the oldest created file:

```
stat -c "%W %n" * |sort -n |tail -n 1
```

which in my case output:

> 1546278526 Desktop

A little note for the OP: I don't know why the option `-c` gives an error, in my system it is necessary to specify a format string.

Comment: The loop isn't really necessary; `stat` accepts an arbitrary number of file arguments.

Comment: The -c gets an illegal option error, but when I remove it I do see what you're getting at. What would be the next step? (since this just gets the info, doesn't sort it). I see you mention `sort` but how would I extract the key to sort by?